# macOS Big Sur version 11.0.1, no paste option in Finder

Tags: macos, copy-paste, big-sur

I upgraded macOS yesterday to Big Sur version 11.0.1, since then there is no paste option in finder, using Cmd + V doesn't work either, just plays a sound.

I can see that the file is copied to the clipboard, but there is no way to paste it. I spent over an hour talking to Apple support on this issue, no solution.

I've searched online and found several posts saying to kill `pboard`, which I've done, still doesn't work.

During the conversation with Apple we created a new account and logged in, everything works on that account, seems that my account which is the one I need is the one thats now broken.

Has anyone got a fix for this?

Comment: When you upgraded, did you wipe the drive clean and migrate your data or did you just install Big Sur on top of whatever you had before?

Comment: No I didn't wipe, I just upgraded.  I can't afford to wipe, to much to keep.  Having spoken with Apple again, they created a new profile, but that has its own problems, now back onto Apple support to get my emails and rules back.

Comment: The problem with not wiping is that you're bringing over old, outdated and sometime incompatible preferences and files to a new system.  OS X (10) is done.  macOS 11 is a whole new OS designed for a new architecture.  If you want reliability, it's always best to do a clean install.  That said..what is it about Big Sur that is so critical that it supersedes in priority over having a stable, working system?  It's a "dot zero" release of a brand new OS - I recommend that anyone who depends on their system always skip these releases until they've release 3 or 4 updates to fix issues.

Answer (score 2):

Any problem that only occurs in one user account has a standard solution:

Your problem is caused by ***something*** in your user account. This could be:

- third-party software that is triggered to launch automatically, or something like a Finder extension.
- A setting or preference that is wrongly configured.
- Something else that exists inside your `~/Library` folder. *(the ~ sign means the current user's home)*

Check **System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items** to see what is set to load at Login. It's possible that one of those might be incompatible with Big Sur and causing problems. Check for updates. Disable all of them, reboot and test the problem.

Check Finder Extensions in **System Preferences > Extensions**. Test the problem with any third-party extensions disabled. (You'll need to reboot or restart Finder, at least.)

Check the LaunchAgents folder in the `~/Library`. This may contain scripts that trigger background apps. These may need updating. Again, remove the plist files to another location, reboot and test.

If none of those things work, then you'll need to 'divide and conquer'. Start removing entire folders from the `~/Library`, reboot and test. If the problem is still there, replace the folder. If it goes away, restore half the contents of that folder, and test again. Gradually, you'll focus on the problem.

Likely folders are the `Preferences` folder, which contains ... well, preferences; and the `Containers` folder, which contains individual apps' working files.

Note that this is all in the user's `Library`, not the root level `Library`. The user's `Library` may be hidden in the Finder. Hold the Option key and click on the Go menu in the Finder, and Library should be a menu item.

**Things not to do:**

- Don't reinstall the OS. The OS is working fine, as shown in the new user account. That will do nothing, except waste your time.
- Don't migrate to the new user account. Changing user account can cause problems with existing file permissions. Also, if it happens again, will you keep moving on to new account after new account?

Comment: To late, was back onto Apple support today and they created a new account, but now there are lots of other issues, like trying to get my emails back and the rules, also software like Qt that was working before now has issues building.

Comment: Do you not have a backup that you can restore?

Comment: I'm now back up and running, had to create a new profile...now smaller issues but still issues.